# How to run loop check vbs for particular running process? Or missing process?

Tags: vbscript

I am running the following VBScript (`check.vbs`):

```
Set service = GetObject ("winmgmts:")

For Each Process In Service.InstancesOf("Win32_Process")
    If Process.Name = "cmd.exe" Then
        WScript.Echo "cmd running"
        WScript.Quit
    End If
Next
CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run("C:\system\file.bat")
```

This script will check whether `cmd.exe` is running or not. If it is running, this script will display a message "cmd running". If it is not running, this script will open a batch file `C:\system\file.bat`.

But what I actually need is: when I run this script `check.vbs` it needs to keep on checking until it finds that `cmd.exe` is not running.

Only if it found `cmd.exe` is not running it needs to run `file.bat` - after repeated checking in background (like any loop program).

**In simple words,** when opening `check.vbs` the script need to continously check that `cmd.exe` is running or not, once it found it's not running, it need to open `file.bat`.

Comment: Your code should already do what you described. Or do you mean you want to repeat after either CMD was found or `file.bat` was executed? In an infinite loop?

Comment: i need a continous loop program, which keep on checking the process. if cmd.exe missed in process it need to open `file.bat`. incase cmd.exe process is opened somewhere the `check.vbs` program need to keep on checking continously. "Continous check" for process. if cmd open keep checking until it close. when closed auto open `file.bat`

Answer (score 1):

Still not sure if I understand the question correctly, but assuming that you actually want a monitor that watches and re-spawns a particular process you could do something like this:

```
Set wmi = GetObject ("winmgmts://./root/civm2")

Sub CheckProcess(name, script)
    For Each p In wmi.ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_Process")
        If p.Name = name Then Exit Sub
    Next
    CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run script
End Sub

Do
    CheckProcess "cmd.exe", "C:\system\file.bat"
    WScript.Sleep 100
Loop
```